# How to prevent the event handler in a nested element within the target element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-events

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Ok the thing is that the `<tr>` node have the event listener `$('tr').click(handler1)`. But I don't want the `<a>` node have the same behaviour as the  has.

Is there anyway I can do it without jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a event handler to the a as well and prevent default

```
$(function(){
  $("tr a").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

### Update:

batter yet if you want the link to continue doing the default action but you don't want the event to bubble up to the tr change it to `e.stopPropagation();` instead of `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Exactly what I want, also +1 for e.stopPropagation

Answer (score 2):

You can look at something like this as an alternate to using jQuery

```
document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName == 'A'){
        alert('Clicked A')
    }else{
        alert('clicked tr')
    }
    }, false);
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f9gGx/)

With jQuery:

```
$('tr').on('click', function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('a')){
        alert('clicked a')
    } else {
        alert('clicked tr')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f9gGx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr').click(function(e){    
     if($(e.target).is('#youranchorelementid')){ //you can use class also if you have many elements
    e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```